# How to disable Empty Recycle Bin confirmation dialog?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows 7 (at least) when one chooses Empty Recycle Bin from the RB menu, one gets prompted with a dialog like:

> Are you sure you want to permanently delete these 11 items?

(modulo the actual number of items mentioned).

Is there a way to disable this dialog (without disabling the use of the RB altogether)?

---

NOTE 1: This dialog comes up *even if* one has unchecked the box labeled "Display delete confirmation dialog" in the RB Properties dialog (as long as the RB has not been disabled).

NOTE 2: As alluded to above, any answer that entails disabling the use of the Recycle Bin altogether is explicitly ruled out.  This includes any answer that involves selecting the button labeled "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin.  Remove files immediately when deleted." in the RB Preferences window.

NOTE 3: This question has nothing to do with Outlook Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/78946-can-i-disable-recycle-bin-delete-confirmation.html), that is not possible - it is only possible to remove the confirmation when moving files to the recycle bin.

Comment: +Thanks!  It turns out that at the same site there's a link to a [recipe](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-empty-recycle-bin-confirmation-windows-7/) for doing what I wanted to do.  This recipe does involve installing additional software (nircmd.exe, free) and modifying the registry, but it gets the job done.

Comment: also, the solution includes a handy .reg undo file in case you needed to turn the confirmations back on.